# Angular app with ui-router not hitting controller unless its inline function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I am having trouble with ui-router. If I use an inline function it works, otherwise when I click on the route the controller is not used. I can debug the browser and the js is being delivered but no break points are ever touched.

```
//This is the error when I go to the non working route
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=Provider%20%3C-%20%20%3C-%20MainCtrl

//The commented main route works
(function(){
angular.module('invNodeServer',[
        'ui.router'

])
    .config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $stateProvider
            .state('main', {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: "app/main/main.html",
                controller:'MainCtrl',
                controllerAs:'vm'
            })
            //.state('main', {
            //    url: "/",
            //    templateUrl: "app/main/main.html",
            //    controller:function($scope){
            //        $scope.title = 'Main'
            //    }
            //})

    })
    })();


// This is the controller for the non working route
(function () {
'use strict';
var controllerId = 'MainCtrl';

angular.module('invNodeServer').controller(controllerId, MainCtrl);

MainCtrl.$inject = [''];

/* @ngInject */
function MainCtrl() {

    /* jshint validthis: true */
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Main';
    vm.activate = activate;

    activate();

    ////////////////

    function activate() {
    }
}
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$injector/unpr?p0=Provider` states that the dependency for which you
>   are asking isn't register in module.

That is because you are asking injector to give `''` (blank dependency) on this line, so injector doesn't find any dependency on that name(its obvious) & throwing an error of `$injector/unpr?p0=Provider`.

```
MainCtrl.$inject = [''];
```

For fixing the issue, you should keep it blank like below.

```
MainCtrl.$inject = [];
```

Comment: Your correct that was obvious.Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @JamesMorris Glad to help you on that... Thanks :)